# JODConverter: StarOffice.ServiceManager started but its pid could not be found

Tags: java, libreoffice, pdf-conversion, jodconverter

I've faced with next problem while starting **officeManager**:

> A process with acceptString
>   'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager'
>   started but its pid could not be found

```
@Configuration
public class LibreOfficeConfig {

    @Value("${libre.office.path}")
    private String officeHomeDirectory;

    @Bean
    public OfficeManager officeManagerConfig() {
        return LocalOfficeManager.builder()
                .install()
                .officeHome(Paths.get(officeHomeDirectory).toFile())
                .install()
                .build();
    }
}

public class LibreOfficeConversionServiceImpl implements DocumentConversionChain {
    private void startOfficeManager() {
        if (!officeManager.isRunning()) {
            try {
                officeManager.start();
            } catch (OfficeException e) {
                throw new RedactionServiceException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell us which OS you are using ? Also, you could try to set the log level to TRACE. You will have a better log file to work with for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In my win7 dev environment, I'm facing the exact same exception:
"org.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: A process with acceptString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager' started but its pid could not be found"

I searched Google and found little info, but someone says:

> jodconverter config folder CANNOT have chinese letters!

I've tried all efforts to reinstall LibreOffice, pre-start its service, all failed!

Finally, I changes my win7 default language from Chinese back to English, thus solve upper "pid could not be found" exception!

Hope that can make sense.

Comment: I have the same question, but it happened sometimes, not every time; Your problem happened every time ?